# create a executable with electron who launch cypress

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

i want to create an executable for product manager it's a application in electron
who launch cypress (later in headless, and form for variables),
it works in dev environnement (npm start).
But when i want build the app, the executable works but it doesn't launch cypress.
Do you have a solution ?

Here is my starter :
package.json

```js
{
  "name": "aramis-ara",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron-forge start",
    "package": "electron-forge package",
    "make": "electron-forge make"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@electron-forge/cli": "^6.0.0-beta.54",
    "@electron-forge/maker-deb": "^6.0.0-beta.54",
    "@electron-forge/maker-rpm": "^6.0.0-beta.54",
    "@electron-forge/maker-squirrel": "^6.0.0-beta.54",
    "@electron-forge/maker-zip": "^6.0.0-beta.54",
    "cypress": "^5.6.0",
    "electron": "^10.1.5"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "electron-squirrel-startup": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "config": {
    "forge": {
      "packagerConfig": {},
      "makers": [
        {
          "name": "@electron-forge/maker-squirrel",
          "config": {
            "name": "aramis_ara"
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "@electron-forge/maker-zip",
          "platforms": [
            "darwin"
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "@electron-forge/maker-deb",
          "config": {}
        },
        {
          "name": "@electron-forge/maker-rpm",
          "config": {}
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

main.js for electron

```js
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron');
const exec = require('child_process').exec;

function execute(command, callback) {
  exec(command, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
      callback(stdout);
  });
};

function createWindow () {
  execute('./node_modules/.bin/cypress open', (output) => {
    console.log(output);
  })
  const win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true
    }
  })

  win.loadFile('index.html')
  win.webContents.openDevTools()
}

app.whenReady().then(createWindow)

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit()
  }
})

app.on('activate', () => {
  if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
    createWindow()
  }
})
```

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps good idea to add debug tools on your electron app also in production mode for understand what it happening